# Resharper force space after curly bracket and before closing bracket

Tags: resharper

Resharper is giving me this:

```
new MyObject {Prop1 = prop1, Prop2 = prop2}
```

But I want:

```
new MyObject { Prop1 = prop1, Prop2 = prop2 }
```

Currently it's breaking my StyleCop rules.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I think this is the setting you are looking for.

<strike>http://screencast.com/t/nEXMHo6Ko</strike> Dead link

--Edit--

In case of a dead link, The setting is under C# -> Formatting Style -> Spaces -> Within single-line initializer braces. Check the box next to it and you'll be all set.

Comment: Thanks.  Don't understand why it's not the default.

Comment: Seems this option has been renamed: `Spaces | Around braces | Within single-line expression braces` Or add it directly to the .DotSettings file: `<s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/SPACE_WITHIN_SINGLE_LINE_ARRAY_INITIALIZER_BRACES/@EntryValue">False</s:Boolean>`

Answer (score 0):

you can get resharper to match stylecop here by putting these lines in .editorconfig

`resharper_space_within_empty_braces = true`
`resharper_space_within_single_line_array_initializer_braces = true`