# Format inline anonymous type with ReSharper to be compliant with StyleCop

Tags: c#, resharper, anonymous-types, stylecop

I have the following code:

```
var newItems = items.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Name });
```

ReSharper reformats this to:

```
var newItems = items.Select(x => new {x.Id, x.Name});
```

Which gives the StyleCop warnings [SA1012](https://github.com/Visual-Stylecop/Visual-StyleCop/wiki/SA1012) and [SA1013](https://github.com/Visual-Stylecop/Visual-StyleCop/wiki/SA1013)
I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066437/resharper-force-space-after-curly-bracket-and-before-closing-bracket) but it doesn't seem to work for anonymous types.

What setting do I need to modify in ReSharper to ensure the reformatting is StyleCop compliant?

Comment: @TimSchmelter typo corrected now, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resharper force space after curly bracket and before closing bracket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066437/resharper-force-space-after-curly-bracket-and-before-closing-bracket)

Comment: @vadimyarovikov That solutions doesn't seem to work for anonymous types.

Comment: What version of Resharper do you use?

Comment: @vadimyarovikov I'm using ReSharper 9.1.1

Comment: have you tried to Suspend and reload Resharper? Cause I have 9.2 version and everything seems ok. Btw, maybe you have another extension for formatting?

Comment: Also, here is the question also about anonymous types and it works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630190/resharper-formatting-disable-remove-spaces-for-anonymous-object-creation

Comment: Can confirm that solution from both answers by vadimyarovikov (that's the same solution actually) works in Resharper 2017.2.2.

Comment: @vadimyarovikov I restarted Visual Studio and the settings is now working. I guess Suspending and reloading ReSharper may have fixed this as well. Turning the setting on and off work as per the solution you provided. I'm happy accept an answer or mark this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option that determines expected behaviour:
`C# -> Formatting Style -> Spaces -> Within single-line initializer braces.`

Also, you probably need to suspend and restart Resharper or restart Visual Studio.